# Paypal Notify_url with custom param not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Same problem as: [Paypal Notify_url with custom param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786904/paypal-notify-url-with-custom-param)

But in the answer there is no explanation why, I am using custom parameter at it's full capacity, so the answer there will not work for me, any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The why is simply that URL parameters tend to get omitted from IPN notifications.  It doesn't always happen, but it does happen, and then you find yourself tearing your hair trying to figure out that why.

As mentioned in my answer on the thread you linked, it's best to use the CUSTOM parameter.  As also mentioned in that answer, if you're maxing out the use of the CUSTOM parameter then you can change your system to save all that data you need in your database, and then just send the record ID in the CUSTOM parameter.  That would then come back in IPN so you can pull the data back out of your DB based on that record ID.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response, I am already using that internal id for a database row contains all the data I want, this is my case specifically, the customer asked for the offer description so I used custom field at it's full capacity, then asked us to send an invoice number entered by the user in the invoice field, now I don't have any pass through variable to use for my database id :( , is there any solution to this problem from your experience?

Comment: I'm not following...you said you're passing an invoice ID now, right?  Just make sure all the data you need within the IPN relates to the invoice ID and you'll be able to pull it all back out.

Comment: This invoice number is not unique for each purchase, and the transaction row in the database contains data only for this transaction, so we can't connect this invoice number with the transaction, I need something unique to identify the transaction which is the primary key of the transaction in the database, so my problem now I need some third pass through variable to pass this database id, so I can keep the other two pass through variables for the customer features

Comment: I'm still not following.  You shouldn't need more than a single "pass through variable".  Everything else should relate to that one ID.  Even if you do have more than one, just pass them in the CUSTOM parameter like:  ID1 | ID2 | ID3 or something like that.

Comment: I am sorry if I can not deliver my problem clearly, our customer asked us to send the offer description in Paypal report, so we are using custom parameter for this, then asked to send an invoice number entered by the user in the invoice field, so now we don't have any pass through variable left, that's why I used the notify_url to send the transaction id, I can't use this invoice number entered by the user to identify his transaction.

Comment: My answer is still the same.  I'm not sure why you aren't understanding.    Say you have an "invoices" table, so that's where your invoice ID is coming from, of course, that you're passing into the invoice parameter.  Now you also have additional information you want to pass.  Create a new table in your db called "invoice_custom_data" or something like that.  Add the same invoice_id to this table along with as many additional fields of data you want to have access to within IPN.  When IPN hits you'll get the "invoice" parameter with the invoice ID, and you can use that to pull out custom data.

Comment: With that method you won't even need the "custom" parameter at all.

Comment: I fully understand you, but the problem is that custom and invoice parameters are for paypal to use, not for me, so I can't relate this invoice number to any data in my side.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.  Those parameters are actually there for you to use as you need...that's specifically what they're for, so to say they're for PayPal and not you doesn't make sense.  I haven't seen anything unique about what you've explained, and I've done this sort of thing for hundreds of clients using those fields.